# Change iOS Keyboard colour from website?

Tags: ios, iphone, webkit

I am developing a website that has a dark background colour.

I know there is a way to natively change the keyboard colour with Swift. For example, like this:

[image]

Is there anyway to achieve this same result using CSS or JS when iOS users open my website in a browser?